# Covert String to Key-Value Pair or JSON in dart

Tags: json, dictionary, dart

I have a String which contains key-value pairs, each key-value pair is surrounded by curly braces `{}` and separated by comma `,`

I know we can use `json.decode` or `jsonDecode` but the problem is `key` or `value` is not surrounded by quotes `""`.So `json.decode` or `jsonDecode` isn't working for me.

```
var str = "[{key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val1, key2: val2}]";
```

I want this `str` like this

```
[
  {
    "key1":val1,
    "key2":val2
  },
  {
    "key1":val1,
    "key2":val2
  },
  {
    "key1":val1,
    "key2":val2
  }
]
```

I tried `json.decode`

```
{key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val1...
 ^
_ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:935:48)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
```

I tried `json.encode` before decode but it is encoding in a wrong way like this

```
"[{key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val1, key2: val2}, {key1: val1, key2: val2}]"
```

Comment: Are we guarantee that keys cannot contain `:` in their name and values will never contain either `,` or `}` ? Also, is it complete impossible to get the data in a standard data format? It looks like someone have tried use `toString()` as a way to serialize data...

Comment: Yes, the key never contain `:`  and value is of type `double` (I will convert) so it contains `.` in it. I think that doesn't conflict

Comment: And it is absolutely impossible to receive the data without the destroyed formatting? Since it would be wasteful to make a solution for this problem if there was an easier way to solve the problem. :)

Comment: Actually, the data is coming from a database, the data is in this format itself so this is the issue. we can't change the format now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is just a fast horrible hacky solution which can with high probability be improved. But I hope it gets closer to a solution for you:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var str =
      "[{key1: 0.1, key2: 0.2}, {key1: 0.3, key2: 0.4}, {key1: 0.5, key2: 0.6}]";

  str = str.replaceAll(' ', '').replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'([\{,])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:)'),
      (match) => '${match[1]}"${match[2]}"${match[3]}');
  
  print(str);
  // [{"key1":0.1,"key2":0.2},{"key1":0.3,"key2":0.4},{"key1":0.5,"key2":0.6}]

  final jsonObject = jsonDecode(str) as List<dynamic>;
  jsonObject.forEach(print);
  // {key1: 0.1, key2: 0.2}
  // {key1: 0.3, key2: 0.4}
  // {key1: 0.5, key2: 0.6}
}
```

Comment: Great answer, Thanks a lot. Can you explain me a little bit of this part `(match) => '${match.group(1)}"${match.group(2)}"${match.group(3)}')`. Thanks again

Comment: `replaceAllMapped` finds a given match based on e.g. RegExp. In our case, we want to have a broad search but want to replace a specific part of each finding. So my RegExp have three capture groups (defined with `()`) and I am then using these to create the result we want. So you can e.g. see the first capture group is either `{` or `,` so I cannot just insert one of these but needs to use the one from my match. So that is why I use `replaceAllMapped` where I can specify the exact logic for what I want a given finding to be replaced with.

Comment: So group 1 is either `{` or `,`, group 2 contains the name of our key and group 3 contains always `:` (but I just found it easier to make use of the same pattern. So `'${match.group(1)}"${match.group(2)}"${match.group(3)}'` inserts "" around the name of the found key (group 2) and inserts whatever group 1 is before and group 3 after.

Comment: Oh great, I think like as it is but unfortunately I am not able to do that programmatically. Thanks again